# Compare two or more docx file

Tags: python, python-3.x

i'm new to python. I'm trying to make a program that compares 2 or more docx files. This is for my school, the exams has a lot of repeatedly questions. So, here's the code:

```
import re as pattern
from docx2python import docx2python

file1 = docx2python('/Users/ricar/Downloads/Algas.docx',
                    '/Users/ricar/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/TI/Wamp/BancodoLeitor')

file2 = docx2python('/Users/ricar/Downloads/Alguinhas.docx',
                    '/Users/ricar/OneDrive/Área de Trabalho/TI/Wamp/BancodoLeitor')

matches = pattern.finditer(str(file1.text).replace('(', '').replace(')', ''),
                           (str(file2.text).replace('(', '').replace(')', '')))

for match in matches:
    print(f'você encontrou o seguinte trecho: {match}')
```

there's no error at all, but I think that the "pattern.finditer" are using the entire file1 as a pattern, instead of comparing line for line and see if anyone matches. When I use the same docx file as 'file1' and 'file2' it returns the matches.
Maybe I shoud try to use another module?
Can anyone help me? Thank you.

Comment: `finditer` accepts a regex pattern as its first argument and a string to search through as its second argument according to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/re.html#re.finditer); you're not using it that way though. What do you expect it to do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you just need to split the lines. Try:

```
pat = “|”.join(re.escape(line) for line in str(file2.text).splitlines())
srch = re.compile(pat)
for line in str(file1).splitlines():
    if (match:=srch.search(line)):
        print(f’encontraste {match}’)
```

And then look in the groups for info on where the match was found.
Scroll to the bottom [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for a potentially fun illustration of ‘finditer’.

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 0):

get rid of all the formatting, leave text only, and call `diff` utility with it - do not reinvent the wheel